# Use a value as a name variable in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to use a value as a name variable in Python? 
See next example, using the pandas dataframe, we have the variable column_to_work that later the value is used in the second line of code as variable name:

This piece of code is working fine, but need to be update manually each time the value of 'column_to_work' changes. I am trying to avoid this to automatize the process.

```
column_to_work = 'column_A'

data = csvdf[~csvdf.column_A.isin(processed_list)]
```

I had tried using eval(), globals(), locals()...

```
data = csvdf[~csvdf.eval('column_to_work').isin(processed_list)]
```

but getting similar error always:

```
'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]` for select by variable:

```
data = csvdf[~csvdf[column_to_work].isin(processed_list)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use another syntax:

```
column_to_work = 'column_A'

data = csvdf[~csvdf[column_to_work].isin(processed_list)]
```

This will work the same way.